# Adding jQuery code in Sharepoint

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I am completely new at SP design/dev, and I want to add custom jQuery code to the **Format text > Edit Source**:

```
$('#div1 ul li').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).find('a').animate({'top': '0%'}, 300);
    }, 
    function(){
        $(this).find('a').animate({'top': '75%'}, 300);
    }                 
);
```

It tells me that I need to 'use the embed command'.

How do i do that?